# Why do I get a color noise map when I use an array of floats with imshow() but if I use uint8 I get the image I want?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, computer-vision

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

files = ### 100 portrait photos
imgs = [ plt.imread( f_i ) for f_i in files ] # We read all file compositions into imgs
data = np.array( imgs ) # Turn everything into np.array format
mean_imgs = np.mean( data, axis= 0) # Takes the mean of the entire data set

plt.imshow( mean_imgs ) # imgs_mean = array of floats
```

result:  [image]

```
plt.imshow( mean_imgs.astype( np.uint8 ) ) # Cast mean_imgs into type uint
```

result: [image]

This is probably more of a computer vision question, anyways I am trying to understand the difference between imshow() an array with all floats and an array with type uint8. Can some one kindly explained to me what happened in the backend between these 2 operations?

Please ignore the variable mix up in the pictures. Just think of them as a same variable with different type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`imshow` documentation](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) (emphasis mine):

> The value for each component of MxNx3 and MxNx4 **float** arrays should be in the **range 0.0 to 1.0**.

If the type is `uint8` it expects values to be in the range 0 to 255.

Since converting to `uint8` gives you the correct results your values are obviously not in range 0.0 to 1.0.

This should work:

```
plt.imshow( mean_imgs / 255 )
```

Answer (score 4):

Matplotlib's [imshow](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) method expects float arrays to have values between 0.0 and 1.0. Otherwise, some truncation happens (like overflow, except over 1) so in effect only fractional parts get used, resulting in the noise you see.

If your floats are on the scale 0...255, you can avoid the issue by scaling them: `plt.imshow(X/255)`

Example:

```
X = np.add.outer(np.add.outer(np.arange(0, 50, 0.3), np.arange(0, 50, 0.1)), np.arange(0, 60, 20))
plt.imshow(X)
```

[image: noise]

```
plt.imshow(X/255)  #  same as imshow(X.astype(np.uint8))
```

[image: rgb]